# Basel Geometric Packing

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, reference-request, packing-problem

It's a famous result that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

Or spelt out

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + ... = \frac{\pi^2}{6}  $$

Now if we identify each $\frac{1}{k^2}$ with a $\frac{1}{k} \times \frac{1}{k}$ square. A variety of questions can arise of the form "given a shape of area $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ can it be completely covered by squares of sidelength $\frac{1}{k}$?"

Are there any famous examples of this? How about just a $\frac{\pi}{2} \times \frac{\pi}{3}$ rectangle?

Comment: why Basel?...........

Comment: was trynna make a reference to the "Basel Problem" from  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: Probably. Useful references: https://doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1997.2836 https://youtu.be/nm6PBABTGdo https://sites.google.com/site/clivet/zeta2

Comment: Similar problem can be seen at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2645195/195155 but there, it seems, there is a good chance the squares pack.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot fit a $\frac14 \times\frac14$ square into your $\frac{\pi}{2} \times \frac{\pi}{3}$ rectangle.
[image]

Comment: I would have added explanatory text in addition to the diagram. Something like "Since $1 + 1/i > \pi/3$ for $2 \le i \le 21$, the squares of sides 1/2, 1/3, and 1/4 must fit in a rectangle of size $\pi/2-1$ by $\pi/3$. Since $\pi/2-1 \le 1/2 + 1/4 \le 1/2 + 1/3$, the squares of sides 1/3 and 1/4 must fit in a rectangle of size $\pi/2-1$ by $\pi/3 -1/2$ but this is obviously impossible since 1/3 + 1/4 is greater than the larger side of that rectangle."

Comment: Another problem with your proof is that you don't explicitly address the situation where the squares are not "axis-aligned". Still, certainly worth an up-vote.