# Can the squares with side $1/n$ be packed into a $1 \times \zeta(2)$ rectangle?

Tags: rectangles, packing-problem

As is well-known the total area of the squares with sides $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots$ is $\pi^2/6$. But can a $1 \times \pi^2/6$ rectangle be tiled with those squares? I have packed the first $10^{10}$ such squares into the rectangle using a simple greedy algorithm.

The packing program represents the available space by a set of rectangles. I call these rectangles splinters. So, to start with, there is exactly one splinter. The program records the width and length of each splinter - with the convention that the length is always greater than, or equal to, the width. When trying to pack a square of side k (where k = 1/n, for some n) it will find the splinter with the smallest width that will accommodate the square. If there are several suitable smallest-width splinters, all with the same width, the program chooses one arbitrarily. The program does not need to check that the length of the splinter is sufficient to accommodate the square because the length of a splinter is always greater than or equal to its width.

Let the chosen splinter have width W and length L. That splinter is deleted from the list of splinters and two new splinters are inserted with dimensions W × (L-k) and k × (W-k). For each new splinter the program must determine which dimension is the new width and which is the new length. By the way, the splinters are held in a binary search tree.

An obvious, but important, optimization is a consequence of the fact that the program, when started, is given a target number of squares to pack. Thus it knows the size of the smallest square it will ever pack. So, if ever it is about to create a splinter with a width less than the side of the smallest square, it can immediately discard it - that space could never be used. In the case of packing 10 billion squares the number of splinters rises to about 2.7 million after about 230 million squares and thereafter slowly declines until, after the 10 billionth square has been packed, just two splinters remain.

Note that, as far as this packing strategy is concerned, the position and orientation of a splinter is unimportant. Equally, which of the four corners of the splinter is chosen as the home for a new square is arbitrary.

Fwiw, I have now packed in a trillion, $10^{12}$, squares.

In my very first attempts at this packing I used Mathematica to do all the arithmetic, and I just specified the long edge of the rectangle as Zeta[2].

Later, I moved away from Mathematica for this job and used unlimited-precision rational arithmetic in a C# program and specified that the long edge was some high precision rational just less than Zeta[2].

Most recently I have been using an approach where (effectively) all the rational numbers used have the same denominator, (d, say). So I can think of the original rectangle to be an array of square dots, each dot being of side 1/d. So, the "1" side would contain d dots, and the Zeta[2] side would have m dots where m/d is just less than Zeta[2].

Each square packed in has its side, 1/n, rounded up to a fraction whose denominator is d. [Obviously I do not need to actually store any denominators - they are all the same.] Thus each square packed covers a square patch of dots.

Using this method I was able to pack $10^{12}$ squares in about 26 hours. The exact value of d does not seem critical. I did the trillion square packing a couple of of times:

- Once with d=11,214,275,663,373,188,676 - which makes m (the number of dots in the long side) just less that $2^{64}$-1 (I use unsigned 64-bit integer arithmetic for all the bookkeeping).
- And once with d=9,419,588,158,802,421,600 - the LCM of the integers from 1 to 46.

Note, however, that d must be a multiple of 6, otherwise the 1/6 square cannot be packed.

Something that surprised me was that relatively small values of d will allow relatively large numbers of squares to be packed:

d=450 is the smallest d that will allow the first 100 squares to be packed. (The 1/101 square fails.)

d=13,104 (=$2^{4}$ × $3^{2}$ × 7 × 13) is the smallest d that will allow the first 1,000 squares to be packed. (The 1/1,003 square fails.)

d=163,800 (= $2^{3} × 3^{2} × 5^{2} × 7 × 13$) is the smallest d that will allow the first 10,000 squares to be packed. (The 1/10,020 square fails.)

d=1,848,000 (= $2^{6} × 3 × 5^{3} × 7 × 11$) is the smallest d that will allow the first 100,000 squares to be packed. (The 1/101,057 square fails.)

d=36,756,720 (=3∗LCM(1 to 17)) allows the first million squares to be packed in, but there are probably smaller values of d which would also allow that packing. With this value of d my program packs in the first million squares in 73 milliseconds. The first failing square with this d is 1/1,352,878.

I now think that the smallest d which allows a million squares to be packed is probably 22,515,570 (=$2×3^{4}×5×7×11×19^{2}$). This d-value first fails on packing the square with side 1/1,000,784. If there is a smaller d which allows the million-square packing, then that d is less than 22 million.

Comment: actually, with the sides as in the body of your question, the total area is $\zeta(4) = \pi^4 / 90$

Comment: If you want total area of $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, you need squares with sides $\frac 11,\frac12,\frac13,\cdots$

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected my question.

Comment: Maybe you should post a diagram showing where, say, the first ten squares go. I guess I see: up to any given $n$ there will be open gaps. However, these can be filed in to a large extent by much smaller squares. Without a very clear description of placement, it might be  hard to prove that this is possible, also very hard to prove impossible.

Comment: 'The program does not need to check that the length of the splinter is sufficient to accomodate the square' - I'm not sure how this can work. After you pack the $1\times1$ square, for instance, you're left with a $1\times(\pi^2/6-1)$ rectangle. If you then pack (e.g.) the $1/2\times 1/2$ square into one corner of this, you're left with a region of width(?) $1/2$ but length $\pi^2/6- 3/2 \approx .145\ldots$, but this certainly can't pack the square of side $1/3$ even though its width would suggest it can.

Comment: @steven Let the dimensions of the starting splinter, before any squares have been inserted, be width=1, length=Z.

After inserting the 1×1 square we have just one splinter: width=Z-1, length=1.

After inserting the 1/2×1/2 square we now have a total of two splinters: width=Z-3/2, length=1/2 and width=1/2, length=Z-1. [The length is never less than the width.]

The second of these splinters will clearly accommodate the 1/3×1/3 square.

Comment: Related questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278268/can-squares-of-side-1-2-1-3-1-4-be-packed-into-three-quarters-of-a-unit-squ/278275 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles and probably others.

Comment: How do you represent the numbers?  If you use floating point, how does your representation take into account the finite accuracy?  Do you round up?  In other words, the square of side 1/3 is underrepresented as merely 0.3333333333333 with a truncation error.  Those errors are small but accumulate when talking 10^12 squares.  Or do you use some other representation?

Comment: @BrianTrial I have edited my question to answer your queries.

Comment: Have you considered packing into a $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\times\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$ square instead?

Comment: @alex.jordan Only the 1x1 square could be packed.

Comment: @CliveTooth Ah, I see. And it looks like maybe $\frac{\pi}{2}\times\frac{\pi}{3}$ can get to the $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}$ square, but not to the $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @alex.jordan Quite so.

Comment: Not that this is particularly interesting given the practical results presented but for the record, a result of Moon and Moser ("Some packing and covering theorems", Colloquium Mathematicum 1967 vol. 17 pg. 106 Theorem 4) proves that the squares in question can certainly be packed into a rectangle of double that area, of width $2 \zeta(2)$

Comment: Hi Clive.  Out of curiosity, I duplicated most of your results.  I run into memory limitations with 10^12, though I did manage 10^11 in only 28 minutes.  I use a Skip List instead of a binary tree to take advantage of the fact that new squares are placed in splinters that are larger than most, so I search for those left to right, and the newly created splinters are smaller than most, so I insert those searching from right to left.  It was helpful to have your intermediate results for 10^3 - 10^6, I duplicate these results exactly, which gives me great confidence in the results.

Comment: @BrianTrial Hello Brian, I am very happy that your results agree with mine. If you drop me an email [clivet@gmail.com] we could correspond further about this topic.

Answer (score 7):

This answer answers the question only approximately, but at least does so rigorously.

Theorem 4 from

*Moon, J.W.; Moser, L.*, Some packing and covering theorems, Colloq. Math. 17, 103-110 (1967). [ZBL0152.39502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0152.39502).

states: Let there be given a set of squares of total area $A$ the largest of which has side $D$. Such a set can be packed in any rectangle of area $2A$ and shorter side $B$, if $D\le B$.

Therefore if a packing exists of the largest $n-1$ squares into the rectangle of size $1 \times \zeta(2)$, and $A = \sum^\infty_n {1\over{n^2}}$ is the total area of the remaining squares, the remaining squares fit into a rectangle of size $1 \times \max(1/n, 2A)$ which can be adjoined to the larger one, giving a packing of the entire set of squares into a rectangle of size $1 \times (\zeta(2)+\max(1/n, 2A))$.

Since you state that a packing exists for the first $10^{12}$ squares, this means that a rectangle not much larger than $1 \times \zeta(2)$ certainly can be packed with all the squares (a naive bound on A yields a width of $\zeta(2) + 4\times 10^{-12}$, if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Part 1/3: Squares 1-9]

This shows a placement of the first 9 squares.  The goal is to keep the unused space as contiguous and usable as possible. Note that the 6 is an exact fill, the 7 nearly so but there is a slight gap at the top.   (fig. 1/3)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Part 2/3: Squares 1-24]

Squares 1-24.  Note the 10 and 15 are an exact placement since 1/3 = 1/6 + 1/10 + 1/15.  Similarly the 20 and 12 are exact fits.  We are keeping a relatively large block of unused space above the 12 and 4. (fig. 2/3)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Part 3/3: Squares 1-60]

Squares 1-60.  This shows there is not an early bottleneck in this problem, and we continue to preserve a relatively large unused space above the 4.  As we start placing squares greater than 60, there is still space above the 8 that can accommodate them, and spaces above the 23 and 47&48 can also be used as squares in the 70 and 80 range need space.  This is not a convincing demonstration for a complete solution, but shows it is possible.  (fig. 3/3)

Comment: This reminds me of a quilt that my wife and I made back in 2018...
https://www.facebook.com/clive.thoot/media_set?set=a.10214369363205571